# React: validateDOMNesting: #text cannot appear as a child of <tr>

Tags: reactjs, warnings

Can you explain me why react show warning `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): #text cannot appear as a child of <tr>. See Router > RouterContext > CarWashPage > AllCarWashTable > tr > #text.`? I don't see any text inside tag `tr`

**Code that renders table**

```
export default class AllCarWashTable extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generateHeaders = this.generateHeaders.bind(this);
    this.generateRows = this.generateRows.bind(this);
};

static propTypes = {
    cols : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    rows : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

generateHeaders() {
    let cols = this.props.cols;  // [{key, label}]
    return cols.map(function(colData) {
        return <th key={colData.key}> {colData.label} </th>;
    });
}

generateRows() {
    let cols = this.props.cols,  // [{key, label}]
        data = this.props.rows;
    if (this.props.rows.length > 0) {
        return data.map(function(item) {
            var cells = cols.map(function(colData) {
                return <td key={colData.key}> {item[colData.key]} </td>;
            });
            return <tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr>;
        });
    }
}

render(){
    let headers = this.generateHeaders();
    let rows = this.generateRows();

    return (
         <table className="table table-hove">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    {headers}
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                    {rows}
             </tbody>

         </table>
    )
}
}
```

At the end, **my table has the following structure**

[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The problem is the spaces in this line:

```
return <tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr>;
```

It might seem silly, but you're actually rendering the cells **and some whitespace** (i.e. text). It should look like this:

```
return <tr key={item.id}>{cells}</tr>;
```

Comment: <table>
          <tbody>{ex_list} </tbody> // Breaks here
        </table>
Fix: <table>
          <tbody>{ex_list}</tbody>
        </table>

Answer (score 100):

This will also happens when using logical AND short-circuit `&&` to show/hide conditional rows:

```
{
  foo && (<tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>)
}
```

change it to ternary `a ? b : c` form where c is `null` will fix it

```
{
  foo ? (<tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>) : null
}
```

Comment: nice, I got this issue. Thanks

Comment: I just figured this out by trying `null`. What if I want a message to appear? For instance, I have a grid of data. If there's no data, I would want a message saying "No data available" instead of just and empty table.

Answer (score 32):

In my case where was an empty `''` output (w\o space inside)

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.orders.map(
    order =>this.props.selectedAgent === order.agent ? 
      <Row item={order} key={ order._id } /> : ''
    )
  }
</tbody>
```

The **null** does the trick:

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.orders.map(
    order =>this.props.selectedAgent === order.agent ? 
      <Row item={order} key={ order._id } /> : null
    )
  }
</tbody>
```

Comment: fixed it for me

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer wasn't the root cause in my case. I got the same warning when I had a comment after `<th>` tag. The warning went away when I removed the comment.

```
const TableHeaders = (props) => (
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th> {/* TODO: I had a comment like this */}
  </tr>
)
```

EDIT: Removing the space between `</th>` and `{/*` will also do the trick.

Comment: Whoever gave -1, would you comment why?

Comment: I didn't give you -1, but the accepted answer, indeed, shows why the error occurred. It it not because of the comment, but it is because the space between the closing `th` tag and the opening curly brace of the comment. Removing the space between them, solves the problem.

Comment: The accepted answer indeed indicates cause, but React is terrible at telling *where* the issue actually is. It told me it was in the parent component :-P  Only after I came across this answer did I recall using a comment which, after adjusting, fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

A `<tr>` HTML tag indicates a table row. So, any text to be displayed inside a table row must be placed inside `<td>` HTML tag. This would remove the error.

Example:

```
return (
    <tr>
        <td> {/* Using <td> inside <tr> */}
            Hello World!
        </td>
    </tr>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Notification warning: `validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>`. Make sure you don't have any extra white space between tags on each line of your source code.
In my case, initialize variable should NOT is `null`.

```
 let elementCart = ''; {/* in the here,warning will append  */}
    if(productsCart.length > 0){
        elementCart = productsCart.map((item, index) => {
            return <CartItem item={item} key={index} index={index} />
        });
    }

    return(
        <tbody id="my-cart-body">
            {elementCart}
        </tbody>
    )
```

Solution: `let elementCart = null;`

Answer (score 3):

Kevin Law (from other comment) said that you can do this:

```
{
  foo ? (<tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>) : null
}
```

But you can also fix it like this:

```
{
  Boolean(foo) && <tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment to the answer from Kevin Law than as an answer on its own.

Comment: I wanted to do that, @sunero4, but I need 50 repu for that.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to upvote, but this was very useful for me. Thanks @MisterJacket

Answer (score 2):

Incase anyone else comes across this error or a similar whitespace error with Material UI in React, my solution after hours of breaking my code was a simple javascript comment inside of my table.

```
 { /*  sortable here */ }
```

I removed that from between my table elements and the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `let` variables are valued otherwise initialize a new empty array.

```
{headers ? headers : []}

or

{rows || []}
```

For me it works like a charm ...

```
render(){
    let headers = this.generateHeaders();
    let rows = this.generateRows();

    return (
         <table className="table table-hove">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    {headers ? headers : []}
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                    {rows || []}
             </tbody>

         </table>
    )
}
```

also `|| null` can solve it.
the important is that the value is not `''`

Comment: This helped me, I replaced `{ isTrue && rows }` with `{ isTrue ? rows : null }` and the warning is gone 

Answer (score 2):

Removing the comment is what helped me too
[image]

Answer (score 1):

in my case initialize a variable with null instead of "" works fine

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jarno's answer, I also ran into this issue as well. Double check that you don't have any additional `}` or `{` at the end of your javascript code:

```
{this.props.headers.map(header => <th key={header}>{header}</th>)}}
                                                                  ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this warning when I had a parenthesis instead of a curly bracket

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      (showMsg && <td>Hi</td>} // leading '(' should be a '{'
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this warning when I put text inside `<tr>` element with no `<td>` elements. I wrapped my text with `<td>` elements and the warning disappeared.

When I did this, having a whitespace in my text or having used {} didn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I **indeed** had a `<tr>` inside a `<tr>` (intended to use `<td>`) :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to find. Just open your inspect and look for  tag. It should appear at the beginning or at the end of the tag a quoted string like this:

[image: Inspect element on google chrome]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass an unexpected element in the table body tag. You should use tr and td

In your rows would return the element with **tr** and **td**

```
{rows}
```

Something like

```
return(
    <tr>
        <td> 
            Hello
        </td>
    </tr>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, I was getting this error because I forgot to update a SQL query to include an updated column name. The original query was trying to access a column that didn't exist.

This query was being used with Nextjs, React, Material UI and sent to a PostgreSQL server in order to load up a MUI front-end table with database information from the table.

Updating the query fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for any of the following reasons:

1. Displaying a blank (`''`) or `false` instead of `null`

```
let foo = '';
...
<tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>}
...
```

OR

```
let foo = null;
...
{foo && (<tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>)}
...
```

OR

```
let foos = [];
...
{foos.length && foos.map((foo) => (
  <tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>
)}
...
```

2. Having an extra space

```
...
{foo ? (<tr><td> {foo} </td></tr>) : null}
...
```

3. Using the wrong tag

```
...
{foo ? (<tr><tr>{foo}</tr></tr>) : null}
...
```

---

###### Correct methods

```
...
<tr><td>{foo || null}</td></tr>

{/* OR */}

{foos.map((foo) => (
  <tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>
)}

{/* OR */}

{foo ? (<tr><td>{foo}</td></tr>) : null}
...
```

Comment: Did you mean `<tr>{foo}</tr>` in the first example? The question was about children to TR, not TD.

Comment: @geon No but the error should happen either way. It is still a child even if nested.

Comment: TD may contain text. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD

Comment: @geon Of course it can. This question is about how to solve a warning from React.