# React Inline Style- Replace tbody With Centered Text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, inline-styles

I have an empty array which I translate into state in React. When the array isn't populated, I would like to add a text saying "no match events yet..." into a `react-bootstrap` Table's `tbody`.

Image is how it looks atm- I'm not sure how to center the text in the middle of the `Card`.

```
  const [matchEvents, setMatchEvents] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Card>
      <Table size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ width: "33.33%" }}>Event</th>
            <th style={{ width: "33.33%" }}>Time</th>
            <th style={{ width: "33.33%" }}>Period</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {matchEvents.length !== 0 ? (
          <tbody>
            {
             //Irrelevant code for mapping object to table in here
            }
          </tbody>
        ) : (
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td />
              <td
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  position: "absolute",
                }}
              >
                No Match Events Yet...
              </td>
              <td />
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        )}
      </Table>
    </Card>
  );
```

I tried adding `<tr>` and `<td>` as filler for the top to get the text into the center of the card, but I got a few lines as borders and wasn't able to overwrite them inline with `!important` for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make the text vertically centered on the card?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan yes please, right in the middle if possible!

Comment: Added the answer please give it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, just copy and paste.

Here you can preview the demo: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-morse-2uq7o?file=/src/App.js)

```
const [matchEvents, setMatchEvents] = useState([]);

  <Card>
    <Table size="sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={{ width: "33.33%" }}>Event</th>
          <th style={{ width: "33.33%" }}>Time</th>
          <th style={{ width: "33.33%" }}>Period</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      {matchEvents.length && (
        <tbody>
          {/* Your Table Body */}
        </tbody>
      )}
    </Table>

    {/* Your Error Message */}
    {!matchEvents.length && (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <p style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>
          No Match Events Yet...
        </p>
      </div>
    )}
  </Card>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah Khan!! It works but I do get a warning on the browser: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <table>. 

Is this safe?

Comment: Yes, everything is safe. Try to remove extra spaces... Reference Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914455/react-validatedomnesting-text-cannot-appear-as-a-child-of-tr

Comment: I have removed spaces between `tbody` try my answer now